# javascript - read out of a text file and insert into a 2d array through a browse button

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you read out of a text file using a browse button and load it into a 2d array?

```
<input type="file" id="fileOpen"> // here is the browse button
```

And here is the text file:

```
530070000
600195000
098000060
800060003
400803001
700020006
060000280
000419005
000080079
```

Comment: Javascript can't access file contents. The only thing you can do with `<input type="file">` is upload the file to a server.

Comment: What you could do is send the file to your server using AJAX, have the server script parse the file, and then send the array back in JSON format.

Comment: BTW, why would that data be in a 2d array? It looks 1 dimensional, what's the second axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync#readAsText%28%29) to read the file. Use the [`files` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) of the `input` element to get a list of `File`s. `File`s are `Blob`s.